# minimization of |X of exponential distribution - c|

Tags: statistics, expectation, exponential-distribution

Let x be distributed exponentially with some mean Θ. We have to find such value c, that $|X - c|$ is minimized.
Since mean or expected number of x is Θ, why can't we just say, that to minimize the abs value of the expression (ie make it equal to zero) we should use c = Θ? That sounds to easy, doesn't it?:(

Comment: Because the mean does not in general minimise the average absolute deviation for non-symmetric distributions

Comment: @Henry thank you, any hints where to start?

Comment: You want to minimise $$\int_{x \le c} (c-x)\,f(x)\,dx + \int_{x \gt c} (x-c)\,f(x)\,dx$$

Comment: @Henry  but what about limits of integration? I suspect the are from 0 to infinity p, so how it is possible to find  c minimising this expression ?

Comment: In this case the density is $0$ for negative $x$ and positive for positive $x$, so $x \le c$ can be read as from $0$ to $c$ while $x \gt c$ can be read as from $c$ to $\infty$

Comment: @Henry no, that was obvious, I was talking about infinity in the limits of the integral so it's impossible to equalise the derivative of the presented expression by u and therefore to find c we need

Comment: What do you think the integral is when $f(x)=\frac1{\theta}e^{-x/\theta}$ ?  It should be a function of $c$